# EF Core Code First Automatic Column Not Deletable

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a Code-First .Net Core project using Entity Framework Core (2.0).

There are two tables, `RhythmBlock` and `RhythmPattern`.

Based on a `List<RhythmBlock>` property on `RhythmPattern`, EF created a column on `RhythmBlock` of `RhythmPatternId`, which I didn't really want.

So I tried all the following:

1. Mark the `List<RhythmBlock>` with the Annotation `[NotMapped]` and update db.
2. User FluentAPI to tell the db to `Ignore` and update db.
3. Delete the `List<RhythmBlock>` and replace with a method that returns the same, updated db.
4. All sorts of shenanigans with resetting the Migrations, direct sql, etc.

The results of all my attempts were that anytime I deleted the column `RhythmPatternId` in table `RhythmBlocks`, I would get the error `Invalid Column Name`. Even if the column and all indexes and foreign keys were deleted, all reference removed from the project, the error would continue.

The only way to get my project running again? Add back in the deleted column. So it's working, but I don't understand why?

Comment: How else would you expect to link `RhythmBlock` and `RhythmPattern`?

Comment: I have them linked with a `RhythmBlockRhythmPattern` many-to-many table

Comment: Do you have a navigation property from RhythmBlock back to RhythmPattern?

Comment: No, only the many-to-many. This is a huge project and I have many classes in the model, with all types of connections. This isn’t an obvious answer. Might be a bug I should file.

Comment: if you want many-to-many relationship, may be it will useful for you http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Again, I am not new to EF or many to many relationships. I have dozens of both one to many and many to many in this project, working successfully. I am simply trying to understand if there’s any way to prevent or remove an unwanted connection being made by EF.